# AngularJS (Angular 1) modelo de $scope no se actualiza

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, model

Estoy tratando de hacer lo siguiente , una consulta a 2 apis.

La primera consulta es para traer los datos de una localidad dada una ciudad , lo manejo con promesas.

La segunda consulta es ,para traer de ese dato 7 datos mas dado longitud,latitud y fecha , la hice haciend uso de una IIFE ,pues trate de hacerlo con $resource pero por mas que intente no podía solucionar problemas con el parseado de json.

Aqui esta el código que hace la consulta a la api para traer los datos y actualizar el model forecast,son 2 , uno para cuando cambia la localización y el otro que invoca directamente a la función que trae los datos.

```
$scope.setLocation = function(loc) {
      $scope.location = loc;
      $scope.getForecastByLocation();

    };

   $scope.getForecastByLocation = function(p) {

      if ($scope.location == '' || $scope.location == undefined) {
        $scope.hasState = 'has-warning';
        $scope.message = 'Please provide a location';

      }

      $scope.hasState = 'has-success';
      console.log("LOCACION==",$scope.location);
      $scope.forecast = openWeatherMap.queryForecastDaily({
        location: $scope.location
      });


      $scope.forecast.$promise.then(function(data){

          for(var i=0;i<data.list.length;i++){
              (function(i) {
              var fecha=Date(data.list[i].dt);
              var fecha2=new Date(fecha);
            if(fecha2.getDate()+(i-1)<10){
             var dias="0"+(fecha2.getDate()+(i-1));
            }
            else{
              dias=fecha2.getDate()+(i-1);
            }

              var fechax=fecha2.getFullYear()+"-"+fecha2.getMonth()+"-"+dias+"Z";
              var lon=parseInt(data.city.coord.lon);
              var lat=parseInt(data.city.coord.lat);
              var url="http://api.openweathermap.org/v3/uvi/"+lat+","+lon+"/"+fechax+".json?appid=943d3a75c72ea297aa73f129275d2140";

            $http.get(url)
            .success(function (dat) {
            data.list[i].radiacion=dat.data;
               console.log("Sucesss=",$scope.forecast.list[i].radiacion)
            });



              })(i);



        }

       });
    }
```

Esta es la parte del código que ejecuta el cambio de localización setLocation(item) y a la vez hace al consulta a las apis , se ejecuta bien cuando lo clickeo desde

```
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div>
        <h1>Listado de ciudades importantes</h1>
            <div class="form-inline" role="form">
                <span class="btn-group" >
                    <button ng-repeat="item in exampleLocations | orderBy:'name':true" ng-click="setLocation(item)" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">{{item}}</button>
                </span>

                <br><br><br><br>
                <span class="form-group {{hasState}}">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="location">Ciudad</label>
                    <input ng-model="location" ng-enter="getForecastByLocation(location)" type="text" class="form-control" id="location" placeholder="Ciudad">
                </span>
                <button  class="btn btn-primary " ng-click="getForecastByLocation(location)">Buscar!</button>

                <span ng-show="message" class="alert"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left">&nbsp;</span>{{message}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Se ejecuta sin ningún problema , pero ahora viene lo siguiente , tambíen tengo un menu lateral con la lista de ciudades,esta , le asigno un evento setLocation(post) , parecido al anterior , se ejecuta con normalidad , en los logs aparece que hace la consulta a la api , cuando muestro el dato que consigue la promesa en el código js que puse arriba , me muestra con normalidad (img 3),sin embargo el $scope.forecast no se actualiza , aqui parte del código que esta en la img2 y muestra el resultado de la consulta a la api.

```
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="">
            <p> FORECAST== {{forecast}}</p>
            <h3>  

                {{forecast.city.name | placeholder:'?'}}, {{forecast.city.country | isoCountry}}
                <small>Lon: {{forecast.city.coord.lon | number:2}} Lat: {{forecast.city.coord.lat | number:2}} Population: {{forecast.city.population | number:0}}</small>
            </h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**//Menu lateral opciones ciudades**

```
  <ul  class="dropbox_citys">
                <li ng-repeat="post in exampleLocations | orderBy:'name':true"  >
                    <a ng-click="setLocation(post)">{{post}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Aqui les dejo unas imagenes ,el primero de lo que quiero hacer en el menu lateral estan las listas de ciudades hacer click y que se actualize el modelo ,$scope.forecast , en los logs haciendo uso del menu lateral o desde la misma interfaz donde estan todas las ciudades las que ven en la pantalla , el resultado es el mismo , las cabeceras son iguales , pero usando el menu lateral no se ejecuta la actualizacion del modelo , $scope.forecast , no se actualiza en el html , aún imprimiendo los datos que salen cuando hacen las consultas los cuales si existen.

**//Haciendo click en el menu lateral No se actualiza**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**//Haciendo click en los botones del index.html#forecast Si se actualiza**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**//Logs es igual para img 1 e img2 **
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sé que es algo simple , sin embargo llevo un buen rato sin hallar el problema , quizás me esté olvidando de algo.
¿Qué podría estar pasando?

**---Update  index.html---**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="openWeatherApp">
........
.......
<body ng-controller="OpenWeatherCtrl">
.............

<div id="page-content-wrapper" class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 sect-2">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 sect-2">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 divs_ini_container">
                                    <h2>Climas</h2>
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 div_ini_01 sect-2" >
                                        <center>
                                              <div ng-view></div>
                                        </center>
                                        <p>
..................
..................
```

**---Actualización 2---**

```
console log de $scope.location
Repositorio:https://github.com/kevinlllR/arquisoft
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La funcion que ejecutas desde el menu lateral  `setLocation(item)` en que controlador esta?

Comment: Hola , las 2 estan bajo el mismo controlado  OpenWeatherCtrl , básicamente toda la app esta bajo ese controlador , la vista lateral es un partial , ya que uso routerProvider para servir las plantillas

Comment: pondré una parte del index.html , ya que poner todo ocuparía mucho espacio .

Comment: Puedes hacer un console.log o alert dentro de la funcion `$scope.getForecastByLocation = function(p) {` sobre $scope.location ? Para ver que llega del menu y que llega del ng-click del boton?

Comment: Hola , si ya lo habia hecho , pero el resultado es el mismo si se actualiza , por algo el input el que esta alado de search se actualiza ya que el modelo de ese input es location , sin embargo lo pondré para que lo vean.

Comment: Subiré el link del repositorio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indagando en tu código me di cuenta que el *scope* que tienes en el menú lateral contra el resto son diferentes:

El menú lateral tiene `id: 3`, mientras que en tu menú donde buscas, y los botones que tienes arriba tienen el `id: 4`.

Revisando el código, me tomé la libertad de poner la variable que mencionas:

He impreso el *forecast*, para ver que tenía:

```
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#/forecast"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/inicio/clima.png" alt="">
        <b><Ciudades/b>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropbox_citys">
        {{forecast}}
        <li ng-repeat="post in exampleLocations | orderBy:'name':true >
            <a ng-click="setLocation(post)">{{post}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="/app/partials/mapa.html"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/inicio/clima.png"
        <b>Mapa</b>
```

Efectivamente sí, cambia cuando le doy buscar en tu menú, pero cambia en el que está del lado del menú.

[image: Efectivamente sí, cambia cuando le doy buscar en tu menú]]

Entonces he llegado a la conclusión que al tener un `ng-view`, con la aplicación de afuera, se comportan de manera diferente los `$scope`.

La solución que se me ocurre en estos momentos es que el *"forecast"* lo vuelvas global, algo como `$rootScope`.

Comment: Gracias por tomarte el tiempo , algo así pensé que con el ng-view se comportaba diferente .